# How to make an iOS app support landscape orientation in XCode?

Tags: xcode, screen-orientation

How to make an iOS app support landscape orientation?

How do you make it support both landscape and portrait,  where you can just press a button to activate it.

Comment: -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{}

Comment: check the link below of [stack overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216920/best-practice-to-support-portrait-and-landscape-views-in-a-uinavigationcontrolle/6229606#6229606

Answer (score 1):

for any new people reading this old post just go to main.storyboard->click on the view controller click on simulated metrics (the fourth icon that pops up, looks kind of like a pentagon belt buckle)
then orientation->Landscape this is for Xcode 5